# IdentityServer 4 same site none cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm using IdentityServer4 with .Net Core 2.0 (Not possible to upgrade at the moment).  I'm trying set the Identity Server cookies to same site none using the following methods, but in Chrome, it is always displayed as lax.

in startup.cs - ConfigureServices method (some of it seems redundant but trying everything)

```
     services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })

        .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });

        services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(

        IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme,
        options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            // options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

in startup.cs - Configure method (tried with and without this)

```
  app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax,
            Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
        });

        // This will write cookies, so make sure it's after the cookie policy
        app.UseAuthentication();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you add IdentityServer, you can try control the SameSite mode here:

```
         var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Authentication.CookieSameSiteMode = SameSiteMode.None;
        })
```

Does that help?

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: Thanks, but CookieSameSiteMode is not recognized.  What version is that for?

Comment: I see it in the docs but I can't upgrade past .net core 2.0  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/577440e3d4481dffd439544bcb9d5c48ea3612bf/docs/reference/options.rst